# google MLKIT shows this error while text recognition : " waiting for the text recognition model to be downloaded. please wait "

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this package : firebase_ml_vision 0.9.3+5 on my flutter app.When I'm using text recognizer it shows the error "waiting for the text recognition model to be downloaded. please wait".
but it does not have problem with face detection or barcode and there works fine.

what is the problem about text recognizer?
I found threads here that gave solution about google play service but it does not work for me. I'm using android version 9 on galaxy s8.

I'm using this project from [github](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire)

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem might be that you forgot to add the internet permission in your manifest so the download can't complete. Add:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

in your **AndroidManifest.xml**
Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: I add this too. But it does not help anymore.

Comment: Next step would be looking at your emulator's storage. Make sure you have enough space in there. If you have enough storage on your emulator, go to AVD Manager and then make sure there's an icon in "play store" column for your emulator. Firebase needs access to google play and some emulators aren't equipped with it.

Comment: I dont use emulator.It is a real device.

Comment: I just reread your question and realized you're using flutter. Sorry, for some reason I assumed you were programming Android Natively. Sorry I'm out of ideas but the issue might be on their end. Try posting an issue on their GitHub

Comment: I found the problem.JUST wait to be download.